NetBeans : port busy
Configuring Xdebug with NetBeans, whatever port I choose, it says it is already busy when clicking on the "Debug" button.
Of course, those ports are not busy... What is going on?
Server is linux
Netbeans is installed on windows system
any port used (9000, 9001, 9003...whatever) it says the same thing (port is busy)
using netstat, port are not busy (they are not listed)
restarting the computer does not change anything.

You would need to provide more info to have some ideas/ways to check that: 1) what OS is that; 2) what exactly port numbers you are trying to use; 3) are they actually busy (what your OS network tool (like netstat / lsof etc ) says about them -- they can be used/reserved by your OS or another tool. In either way -- try restarting your computer, this very often resolves such "suddenly stopped working" situations.
